# how to sample from multiple lists (numbers?

Tags: r, list, sampling

I would like to sample, let's say the ages of 100 persons above 65 years old,
and the probabilities for the age groups are as follows:

```
65-74<- 0.56
75-84<- 0.30
85<- 0.24
```

I know the existence of the sample function and I tried it as follows,but that didn't work unfortunately

```
list65_74<-range(65,74)
list75_84<-range(75,84)
list85<-range(85,100)

age<-sample(c(list65_74,list75_84,list85),size=10,replace=TRUE,prob =c(0.56,0.30,0.24 ))I get the following error
```

I got then the following error

```
 Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
      incorrect number of probabilities
```

So I was wondering what is the proper way to sample from multiple lists.
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's I'll call those three objects *groups* instead since they don't use the `list` function.

The way you define them could be fine, but it's somewhat more direct to go with, e.g., `65:74` rather than `c(65, 74)`. So, ultimately I put the three groups in the following list:

```
groups <- list(group65_74 = 65:74, group75_84 = 75:84, group85 = 85:100)
```

Now the first problem with the usage of `sample` was your `x` argument value, which is

> either a vector of one or more elements from which to choose, or a
>   positive integer. See ‘Details.’

Meanwhile, you `x` was just

```
c(list65_74, list75_84, list85)
# [1]  65  74  75  84  85 100
```

Lastly, the value of `prob` is inappropriate. You supply 3 number to a vector of 6 candidates to sample from. Doesn't sound right. Instead, you need to assign an appropriate probability to each age from each group as in

```
rep(c(0.56, 0.30, 0.24), times = sapply(groups, length))
```

So that the result is

```
sample(unlist(groups), size = 10, replace = TRUE, 
       prob = rep(c(0.56, 0.30, 0.24), times = sapply(groups, length)))
# [1] 82 72 69 74 72 72 69 70 74 70
```

Comment: thanks for the elaborative explanatrion, so with the rep(c(0.56, 0.30, 0.24), times = sapply(groups, length)) statement, you fill up the amount of times the probability list in order to apply to all candiates, however maybe a very stupid question, butI was wondering why there are 6 candiates, intuitively I would think that there are 3 candidates.

Comment: Indeed, run `rep(c(0.56, 0.30, 0.24), times = sapply(groups, length))` and you will see that ages in the same group categories have same numeric value. Not those aren't actual probability; to get individual age probabilities you would need to normalize that vector. You may think that there are three candidates from the way `c(list65_74, list75_84, list85)` *looks*. But once you *evaluate* this expression, you get only six number! And that's not what you want to sample from. Now ultimately `unlist(groups)` contains all 36 candidates, `65:100`.

Comment: You indeed have a special case of sampling, with a certain structure. If you are going to do that many times and, importantly, with different groups, then you may want a function that takes things like `c(65, 74)` as an input, to make things simple. Note also that `range(65, 74)` wasn't a useful thing to write since `range(a, b,  c, d)` is just `c(min(a, b, c, d), max(a, b, c, d)`. So, by definition, `range(65, 74)` is just `c(65, 74)`.